# trying download picture with urlib but HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate picture download from this website but i got error

**CODE**

```
>  import urllib.request
>  rain = "http://www.bom.gov.au/charts_data/IDY20108/current/mslp-precip/IDY20108.mslp-precip.012.png?1634817600"
>   urllib.request.urlretrieve(rain, '/content/download_gambar/rain.png')
```

**EROR**

> HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 import urllib.request
> 2 rain = "http://www.bom.gov.au/charts_data/IDY20108/current/mslp-precip/IDY20108.mslp-precip.012.png?1634817600"
> ----> 3 urllib.request.urlretrieve(rain, '/content/download_gambar/rain.png')
>
> 6 frames /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in
> http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
> 647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
> 648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
> --> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> 650
> 651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
>
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: You likely need to be logged in or have some correct values set in your cookies (like agreeing with a copyright statement or something of the sort) to be allowed to make the download.

Comment: The BoM has recently been cracking down on web scraping though, it's possible this one can be resolved by simply spoofing the User-Agent in the header...

Comment: I was curious, and had a look - that's indeed the case, refer http://reg.bom.gov.au/screenscraper/screenscraper_enquiry_form/; if you try automated access with modified headers, it will work once, but running it again gets you a warning document: "Your access is blocked due to the detection of a potential automated access request. The Bureau of Meteorology website does not support web
scraping: if you are trying to access Bureau data through automated means, you should stop."

Comment: You could probably still get it to work using a web driver for `selenium` though, but be aware you're explicitly going against the terms of use of the site you're scraping, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: so there is no way to automate it safe and constantly right ?

Comment: Well, I suppose what I'm saying there may well be, but 'safe' and 'constantly' don't imply 'in line with terms of use' - odds are you can get it to work and it's not exactly illegal, but it may prompt the BoM to further restricts access to yourself and other users, if they can't combat the scraping effectively.

Comment: i got it, thank you grismar

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method instead!:

```py
import requests # The requests module tends to be much better (in my opinion)
imageRequest = requests.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/charts_data/IDY20108/current/mslp-precip/IDY20108.mslp-precip.012.png?1634817600/content/download_gambar/rain.png")
with open("image.png", "wb") as imgFile: # 'wb' means write to file in binary mode
  imgFile.write(imageRequest.content)
  imgFile.close()
```

Comment: that's work. but there is nothing on that picture